# Selenium VBA not finding an element

Tags: html, excel, vba, selenium, google-chrome

I need your help.

I'm trying to get an information from some websites to help increase productivity at my job, but I'm gonna use a public site that I am using for a personal project that shows the same problem.

This is the website: https://www.sofascore.com/tournament/football/england/premier-league/17

This [First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxivR.jpg) shows what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to click on "By Round" and then "Inspect" (Sorry it's in portuguese, maybe it's not the same term in english).

In the [Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDRLJ.jpg) I show you guys the result. It returns a code.

But when I do the steps from [First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxivR.jpg) again in the same place I get the result that I want as in [Third Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2hER.jpg).

I got the XPath from the [Third Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2hER.jpg) and put it on my code in VBA but it says the element can't be found. I think it's because this part is "hidden".

My question is: Why do I have to search for the code twice in order to get it and how to put it on my code in Selenium VBA?

Thank you !

Comment: Your code trials?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you include a minimum workable example as source code, so one can see what you have tried?

Comment: Hi, guys. I put some images in order to make clearer what I'm asking. Hope it helps.